# How to pronounce "another thing"

Tags: pronunciation

When you pronounce "another thing", should you pronounce the "r" at the end of another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the accent/dialect. If the dialect is *[rhotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English)*, it means the /r/ is pronounced in all positions (pre-vocalically, intervocalically and post-vocalically).

However, if the dialect is *non-rhotic*, it means the /r/ is only pronounced pre-vocalically (before a vowel).

In [Standard British English](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_English), the /r/ is only pronounced pre-vocalically. In [General American English](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_American_English), the /r/ is usually pronounced in all positions.

So the speakers of non-rhotic accent would pronounce 'another thing' without the /r/: /ə'nʌ.ðə.θɪŋ/ while the speakers of rhotic accent might pronounce it with the /r/: /ə'nʌ.ðər.θɪŋ/.

In dictionaries (such as Cambridge online dictionary), 'another' is transcribed as /əˈnʌð.ə<sup>r</sup>/, the superscript **r** means *pronounce the r whenever it precedes a word that begins with a vowel*.

There are also rhotic accents in Britain, such as the [West Country accent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Country_English) and non-rhotic accents in the US such as the *New Yowk* accent.

> When you pronounce "another thing", should you pronounce the "r" at the end of another?

If you want speak with a non-rhotic accent, then don't pronounce it unless it's followed by a vowel.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which dialect the speakers use. In American English, a final /r/ is indeed pronounced. So in "another thing", the /r/ in pronounced, especially in careful speech (eg. television interview or news reporting). In British English, the /r/ is not pronounced.

Comment: In 'Standard' British English, the final 'r' is not pronounced, sure, but there are plenty of regional UK accents which are 'rhotic' (the letter 'r' is pronounced), just as there are plenty of US regional accents (e.g. the classic 'New Yawk' accent)  which are **not** rhotic.

Comment: @Michael Yes, of course. When I say "British English", I'm referring to what's usually referred to as Received Pronunciation English. And when I talk about American English, I'm referring to General American English. The way I use these terms is common and perhaps conventionalized because it is impossible to be very specific, especially in an answer to a broad question.

Comment: An old joke: an American tourist in Edinburgh asks a waitress if she is "from around here". She says "Yes. Why do you ask?" He replies "Because of the nice way you roll your Rs". She smiles and says "Och, that's just my high-heeled shoes".